# How do I ROT encrypt strings with spaces in them?

Tags: c++, encryption

I am currently working on a little program where you prompt the user to input any text they want, and then encrypt it using the ROT-n method. As of right now I can encrypt strings that consist of random letters, words and numbers. The problem is though, I can not encrypt strings that have spaces in them.

**For example:**

"hellomyfriend" will encrypt fine, but,

"hello my friend" will not.

An error window pops up displaying a bit of text and this specific part

**"Expression: string subscript is out of range".**

So, obviously? I am indexing an array with a bad index. If that's the case, where am I doing that?

When I click ok, the program throws an exception in the **encryption function**, in the inner for loop

```
if (_user_text[i] == _alphabet[j])
```

**It throws an exception: "Unhandled exception at 0x0FD9CAB6 (ucrtbased.dll) in Projekt 01 (ÖBO1 - PROG1).exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal. occurred"**'

So I assuming the problem is `if (_user_text[i] == _alphabet[j])` somewhere in there?

---

Start:

```
void uppgift_2() {

    // Uppgift:
    // Du skall skapa en enkel kryptering. Låt användaren mata in en text av typen string, valfri storlek.
    // Skriv sedan ut en krypterad version av strängen med rot3.

    // Array with the alphabet in it
    char alphabet[36] = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z', 
                            '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

    // Variables
    std::string user_text = "", org_string = "";
    std::string temp = "";
    int rot_x = 7; // rot7

    // Prompt user for input
    std::cout << "| Enter in a random text (english): ";
    getline(std::cin, user_text);
    org_string = user_text;

    // Make string lowercase
    for (unsigned int b = 0; b < user_text.length(); b++) {
        char lower_Version = tolower(user_text[b]);
        temp += lower_Version;
    }
    user_text = temp;

    // Encrypting user entered text...
    std::string _encrypted_text = encrypt_string(user_text, alphabet, rot_x);

    // Prints out the original string, the encrypted version and the final decrypted version
    std::cout << "\n| Original version: " << org_string << std::endl;
    std::cout << "| - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - |\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "| Encrypted version: " << _encrypted_text << std::endl;
    std::cout << "| Decrypted version: " << decrypt_string(_encrypted_text, alphabet, rot_x) << "\n\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    main_menu(); // Sends the user back to the main menu

}
```

---

Encryption function:

```
std::string encrypt_string(std::string &_user_text, char(&_alphabet)[36], int &rot_x) {

    // Variable(s)
    std::string encrypted_text = "";
    int array_len = 35;
    int pointer = 0; // Used to determine if a switch from rot7 to rot13 is needed

    // The outer loop goes through each character of the user entered string
    for (int i = 0; encrypted_text.length() < _user_text.length(); i++) {
        // The inner loop finds the correspondent character from the alphabet and uses rot7 or rot13 on it
        for (int j = 0; j <= array_len; j++) {
            // if (selected character from user string) is equal to (the correspondant character in the alphabet)
            if (_user_text[i] == _alphabet[j]) {
                int alphabet_index = (j + rot_x);
                // Checks if alphabet_index is out of range and adjusts accordingly
                if (alphabet_index >= array_len+1) {
                    alphabet_index -= array_len+1;
                }
                // Saves the decrypted character...
                char encrypted_char = _alphabet[alphabet_index];
                // ... and concatenates it to the decrypted string
                encrypted_text += encrypted_char;
                break; // Breaks out of inner loop and lets outer loop get the next character
            }
        }
        pointer++;
        // If five characters have been encrypted, switch to rot13
        if (pointer == 5) {
            rot_x = 13;
        }
        // Go back to rot7 when yet another 5 characters have been encrypted
        else if (pointer == 10) {
            rot_x = 7;
            pointer = 0; // Reset the pointer
        }
    }

    // Returns the final encrypted text
    return encrypted_text;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to make the explanation simpler, we assume that there is only one space character in the input text, though this reasoning still applies to input with more than one space character.

Consider what happens with the inner for loop when `_user_text[i]` is a space character. Since the `_alphabet` does not contain the space character, `_alphabet[j]` will never be equal to the space character in `_user_text[i]`. Because of this the code inside the inner for loop's `if` block is not executed, and more importantly, `encrypted_text += encrypted_char` never executes.

Then the outer for loop will continue executing, and then once it reaches the end of that iteration, the counter variable `i` will increment. However, `encrypted_text.length()` is unchanged because we never appended `encrypted_char` to `encrypted_text`. This means that `encrypted_text.length()` is now equal to `i-1`. If we continue to iterate, `encrypted_text.length()` will stay one less than `i`, as we assumed that there was only one space character in the input.

On the last iteration of the loop, this creates an issue. If we replace `encrypted_text.length()` with `i-1` as we figured out that they are the same for the final iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i - 1 < _user_text.length(); i++)
```

We can add one to both sides of the `<` sign to get the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _user_text.length() + 1; i++)
```

Since `i` will always be less than `_user_text.length() + 1`, it's value on the final iteration of the loop will be `_user_text.length()`. This means that for the last iteration of the outer loop, the below conditional:

```
if (_user_text[i] == _alphabet[j])
```

is the same as:

```
if (_user_text[_user_text.length()] == _alphabet[j])
```

This is indexing past the end of `_user_text`, which is causing the crash, as for a string of length `n` we can index from `0` to `n-1`. This is the issue you are encountering.

For `n` spaces, the conditional on the final iteration of the outer for loop looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _user_text.length() + n; i++)
```

and so the code could crash even before the final iteration.

In order to be able to encrypt space characters, you need to:

1. Add `' '` to the `alphabet` array in `uppgift_2`, and change its size to `37`
2. Change the size of the `_alphabet` array argument in `encrypt_string` to `37`
3. And finally, change `array_len` in `encrypt_string` to `36`